# why My Existing Conditional Formatting Rules set by Excel are Lost after using objWriter->PHPEXCEL-save?

Tags: php, phpexcel

my problem is that i have an already existing excel file with Conditional Formatting rules in a Column, i read it and save it with the next sentences:

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('../files/Reportes.xlsx');

//i set a value

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F6', 10);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

$objWriter->save('../files/Reportes.xlsx');
```

the output file is my Reportes.xlsx file without any Conditional Formating rules :S

i read in a post(a 2010 post)  that this is a bug, im using the 1.7.6 of PHPEXCEL

plz help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that anything `PHPExcel_Writer` doesn't support will get wiped out when you have it save a document.